# WPF call a process from app.xml.cs and wait until event or another thing?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, winforms, events

I try to intregate a registration process with 2 windows (one for login and one for subscribe) in my app.xml.cs.
The problem il when i call the first window with a ShowDialog(), the process still wait until the window close, but if in the first window i call the second and i close the first, the process consider that i close the first and continue the sequence...

My question is very simple : how can i run a process with many windows from the app.xml.cs and wait until a particular event ?

Excuse for my english... a poor french developper ;-)

Comment: Note : the first window call the second and vice versa...the ended action is the sucessful logon or the subscribe of the user.

Comment: So you've got a main window and the user does something - say click a button - to try and log in and your log in window appears? On successful log in you'd like the log in window to close and another one to open?

Comment: Exactly ! I don't know how start the process. I can't use ShowDialog() because when the first window is closed, the startup continue... for example, il the user have no account, he click on subscribe, this action close the logon window and open the subdscribe window...

Comment: Why two Dialogs for Logon/Subscribe? You could make respective UserControls and put both on the dialog. Default would be LogonUC visible, SubscribeUC hidden. If "subscribe" is clicked, you simple change visibility of both UCs et voilá.

Comment: Good idea ! difficulty is that i will use ViewModel with the UserControl and Command for validate user info...

Comment: What's your issue? Surely you can just place your validation code in the command handler for your view model? This tutorial - http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFCustomCommands.aspx is pretty good and this mvvm one is pretty good too if you're struggling with that - http://www.learnmvvm.com/